# Check for lowercase & uppercase letter next to each other in a string?

Tags: php, mysql, regex

Can I use some sort of regular expression / function in PHP or MySQL to check for a lowercase & uppercase letter next to each other?

I would want to detect the "y" & "C" between "Laparoscopy" & "Cataract Surgery".

```
LaparoscopyCataract Surgery
```

More examples...

```
TracheostomyThoracotomy
TracheostomyAmniocentesis
Total Knee ReplacementBarium
```

etc...

I need to explode / separate all of these types of instances by a comma.

Comment: `/([a-z][A-Z])|([A-Z][a-z])/` I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
preg_replace("/([a-z])([A-Z])/", "$1,$2", $yourString);
```

Answer (score 1):

`$string = preg_replace("/([a-z])([A-Z])/", "\$1, \$2", $string);` should do it

edit: too late anyways :p

Comment: Don't need the `{1}`s - It will only match one character by default.

Answer (score 0):

I think

```
preg_replace("/[a-z][A-Z])/", "/1, /2", $str);
```

would work per your requirement.

Comment: I tried:  $string = 'OneTwo';
 echo preg_replace("/[a-z][A-Z])/", "/1, /2", $string);  But, got an error.  How could I turn $string into "One,Two"?

Comment: What was the error? My implementation may not have been 100% correct.

Comment: @Graham `$string = preg_replace("/[a-z][A-Z])/", "/1,/2", $string);`?

Comment: @CodeJockey what's the difference there, other than removing the space character?

Comment: @Matt assigning it back to the string variable and the space is all, I think